# 'Buyer's Remorse' with apt

Tags: apt, updates, aptitude

This morning I installed some updates that asked me if I wanted to replace configuration files:

```
Configuration file '/etc/apache2/envvars'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** envvars (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? N
```

I kept my current configuration, but after that, I started wondering:

Is there a way to see what the new config file would have looked like, after the fact?

Comment: Maybe this helps [How can I install/view the grub file that a recent upgrade was providing but I accidentally ignored?](//askubuntu.com/a/799220)

Comment: There were some files in that directory, but none from the `apache2` update performed this morning.

Comment: Where there's a will there's a way! ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tested this but logic dictates that you could review the file contained in the package that was updating. I'm assuming the apache2 package for your current distribution selectable from [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=envvars) (you can confirm by checking your dpkg.log)

DEB files are archives, which always contain the three files — debian-binary, control.tar.gz, and data.tar.gz. We can use dpkg-deb and tar command to extract and view the files from the deb package, as shown below.

Simply extract the files from the package to a temporary location. As an example:
`dpkg-deb -x  packagename.deb /tmp` Adjusting the package name and target location as necessary.

Having extracted the content of the package, next extract the content of the included data.tar.gz component with `tar -xvzf data.tar.gz`

Locate the included envvars file (you could use `find ./ -name envvars` from the location you extracted the data.tar.gz file.

Having located the file navigate to that directory and use  `diff envvars /etc/apache2/envvars` to display the differences between your current configuration file and the suggested one.
Sources:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/view-and-extract-packages/

`man dpkg`

`man dpkg-deb`

`man diff`

Answer (score 3):

I'm accepting [Elder Geek](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek)'s answer because it works and seems to be the most generally applicable without being too labor intensive.  [Waltinator](https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator)'s answer seems to me that it would work but I am leery of reinstalling.

However, I did come up with 2 additional ways to address this problem.

1. I have a clone of my server running in a Virtualbox VM.  I took a snapshot, applied the update (choosing the package maintainer's versions), copied those versions off to a shared drive, then deleted the snapshot, and did the update for reals.

   Downside: normally I do the update in the virtual machine first before the real machine, so I would have to know to take the snapshot first.  Maybe this is good practice before applying any apache2 update? I will have to think about that.
2. This is the easiest answer of all, but I do not know if it is generally applicable.  I was using `aptitude` and updating `apache2`, and in the `/etc/apache2/` folder, I found copies of the package maintainer's config files that I had rejected!  They were named `apache2.conf.dkpg-dist` and `envvars.dpkg-dist`! How cool is that?

Downside: I don't know if this only happens with `aptitude` and\or `apache2`, this may not be generally applicable.

Comment: Your findings from section 2 apply in general. The program that shows dialogues during package installation like in your question also creates "back-ups" of the old and the new configuration file variants (depending on which one you chose to use).

Comment: Frankly, point 2 should be the accepted answer, because of the reason David gives.

Answer (score 1):

You could recreate the condition, and choose differently.

First, copy `/etc/apache2/envvars` somewhere safe, so, in the worst case, you can restore it.

`dpkg -S /etc/apache2/envvars` tells us that `/etc/apache2/envvars` is part of the `apache2` package, so you can reinstall it via:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2
```