# Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 conflicts

Tags: 20.04, samba

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 terminal only. During installation I was requested to deal with conflicts and in the case of samba smb.conf I decided to leave the old version. Now I would like to insert my old configurations in the new version of the smb.conf. Where can I find the base file?

Then how to deal next time with conflicts during upgrades? I tried to deal with the conflicts during it but it was not very clear what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Related:https://askubuntu.com/q/863071/243321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I would like to insert my old configurations in the new version of
> the smb.conf. Where can I find the base file?

There is a copy of the default smb.conf located at:

```
/usr/share/samba/smb.conf
```